# CSS, HTML: rounded corners Hamburger Menu icon using material-icons class

Tags: html, css, material-icons

Is it possible to have rounded corners for the menu icon using the material-icons class. This is what I currently have:

[image: current icon with not rounded corners]

and this is what I need to have:

[image: desired icon with round corners]

The code I have at the moment looks like this: `<i class="material-icons">menu</i>`

Thanks

Comment: There is one I think check this link https://mui.com/material-ui/material-icons/?query=menu&theme=Rounded&selected=MenuRounded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think because this is an icon you can't change the inner style, I suggest you use SVGs to do what you want and edit as you wish.

```
<svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" aria-labelledby="hamburgerIconTitle" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="none" color="#000"><path d="M6 7h12M6 12h12M6 17h12"/></svg>
```

Try this one.

Comment: Ah okay makes sense, this is actually working for me thanks for that. How would I actually change the dimensions of the icon to 20*20 and the colour white, its currently 12*10 and black respectively

Comment: @Harry You can use a website called [SVG Viewer](https://www.svgviewer.dev/s/18485/hamburger)
Edit the "fill" property and resize it from the box at the bottom
NOTE: the SVG code changes when you change the size, don't change the size using the code.